# Set an environment variable in HoloLens and/or workaround?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

The SetEnvironmentVariable method linked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx) cannot be executed on the MSFT HoloLens. Is there a workaround to setting an environment variable, more specifically, on the HoloLens?

Comment: *Probably* not. The hololens, like other mobile devices, restricts access to the underlying system pretty hard. But I haven't tried and do not currently have access to a device, so I can't even test possible solutions.

Comment: @Draco18s Assuming the same, but I'll leave the question up in hopes one day..